# Acentuação no diretório

Tags: php, arquivo, diretório, acentuação, zend-framework-2

Estou com problema de localização de diretório quando envolve um arquivo ou pasta com acentuação. Segue o trecho abaixo onde tento capturar o tamanho do arquivo:

```
$filepath = "$novocaminho".utf8_encode($arquivo);
$tamanho = filesize("$filepath");
```

Neste caso ele está retornando o seguinte erro:  Warning: filesize(): stat failed for

Em outro caso, onde verifico se é um diretório, quando o diretório está sem acentuação, o `if` retorna `true` caso seja um diretório com acentuação ele retorna `false`.

`if(is_dir(utf8_encode($novocaminho_implode)) == TRUE){`

Os diretórios passados são do tipo `string`.

Já tentei utilizar o utf8_encode().

Comment: utf8_encode() talvez não seja a melhor opção

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Uma sugestão é converter tudo que **entra** no banco de dados (até mesmo renomear **o nome do arquivo**) em entidades html, como segue o código php:

```
$email = addslashes(htmlentities($_POST['email'], ENT_QUOTES,'UTF-8'));
```

Dessa forma, todos os caracteres especiais são convertidos, e na hora de exibi-los, o próprio navegador o interpretará.

---

Será convertido segundo a tabela disponível em http://erikasarti.net/html/acentuacao-caracteres-especiais/

á = á (&aacute)

ã = ã (&atilde)

e assim por diante

Comment: Eu tentei e não funcionou. Quando faço a verificação se é um diretório, ele retorna como false mesmo a string já estar em utf-8.

Comment: Alterou o nome do arquivo para os caracteres correspondentes?

Comment: Sim, ainda sim não foi.

Comment: @JonathandeToni E o $novocaminho? Como ele está?

Comment: É uma string também, no caso eu armazeno navegação utilizando array, assim consigo armazenar,construir e destruir o caminho que o usuário está percorrendo. O $novocaminho é atribuído uma string retornada da função implode().

Answer (score 0):

Verifiquei que o problema pode estar em outro ponto do código:

```
if(isset($novocaminho)){
    if(is_dir($novocaminho) == TRUE){

         $diretorio = dir(utf8_encode($novocaminho_implode));

         while (($arquivo = $diretorio->read()) !== false){
```

Quando a minha string, já alterada com o `UTF-8`, é verificada por `if(is_dir())` ela retorna false, mas apenas retorna false quando a string vem com assentos, caso contrário, ela continua e percorre todo o diretório normalmente.

Seria o caso de alterar todo o meu diretório para ficar sem assentos?, mas tenho que mostrar para o usuário os assentos. Como eu faria se estou mostrando "imprimindo" na tela exatamente o nome dos arquivos e pastas que estão no meu diretório.

Existe outras formas de mostrar o diretório?

Eu passo a pasta por um string `$pastaraiz = "public/data/downloads";`. Pois se eu utilizar o `$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'];` irá passar a minha pasta atual.